# addError() method behavior on FeedItem trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, delete, adderror

I've written a basic trigger on FeedItem, which restricts users not to delete their chatter posts (simplified to clarify my question).

```
 trigger beforeDeleteFeed on FeedItem (before delete) {    
    for(FeedItem fi : trigger.old){            
        fi.addError('Feed cannot be deleted');
    }
 }
```

I'm trying to delete the post from Salesforce Classic UI.

[image]

I'm expecting an error message to be displayed something like this in Classic.
[image]

But, I'm getting an error in the alert. Is this expected behavior? How do I display a meaningful message on a page instead of alert? Any inputs please?

[image]

Comment: Where is the record being deleted from? I find it hard to believe this is the standard UI, either Classic or Lightning. If this is custom code somewhere, you'd need to fix that code.

Comment: @sfdcfox Hi there, I'm trying to delete it from standard UI (Classic UI). I just edited the question. Thanks for looking into this.